# How does one install OpenGrok on Windows Server 2003?

Tags: installation, windows-server-2003, opengrok

From searching around the net (and SO) for how to full text search an SVN repo, I discovered [OpenGrok](http://opengrok.github.io/OpenGrok/). I'm at a bit of a loss as to how to get this thing set up though.

Can anyone provide any pointers on how to get this set up to host on a Windows 2003 server?

Also, I understand it is possible to trigger OpenGrok to re-index upon checking in files. Is there a way to make this happen no matter who checks in the files and how does one do this?

Answer (score 1):

For the installation, just following the instructions in the README.txt of the distribution of opengrok should suffice. It did for me. Just make sure you have all the prerequisites correctly installed. (section Requirements in the README.txt).

from this file:

`Source base must be available locally for OpenGrok to work efficiently. No
changes are required to your source tree. If the code is under source control
management (SCM) OpenGrok requires the checked out source tree under SRC_ROOT.`

Comment: I couldn't quite make sense of the instructions... :(

Comment: SRC_ROOT is where you have to checkout your sources, it's a parameter and you can configure it to point to the directory you want. Tell us where you are stuck and we'll try to help you

Answer (score 0):

To reindex you project run
java -jar opengrok.jar -R D:\ProgramFiles\Grok\opengrok-0.12.1\configuration.xml